# Understanding --archive in dataproc pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

This is what the commmand help says:

> --archives=[ARCHIVE,...]
> Comma separated list of archives to be extracted into the working
> directory of each executor. Must be one of the following file formats:
> .zip, .tar, .tar.gz, or .tgz.

and, this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645635/dataproc-does-not-unpack-files-passed-as-archive) tells me that `--archives` will only be extracted on worker nodes

I am testing the `--archive` behavior the following way :
tl;dr - 1. I create an archive and zip it. 2. I create a simple rdd and map its element to `os. walk('./')`. 3. The `archive.zip` gets listed as a directory but `os.walk` does not traverse down this branch

My `archive` directory:

```
.
├── archive
│   ├── a1.py
│   ├── a1.txt
│   └── archive1
│       ├── a1_in.py
│       └── a1_in.txt
├── archive.zip
└── main.py

2 directories, 6 files
```

Testing code:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(1))
walk_worker = rdd.map(lambda x: str(list(os.walk('./')))).distinct().collect()
walk_driver = list(os.walk('./'))
print('driver walk:', walk_driver)
print('worker walk:',walk_worker)
```

Dataproc run command:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark main.py --cluster pyspark-monsoon31 --region us-central1 --archives archive.zip
```

output:

```
driver walk: [('./', [], ['.main.py.crc', 'archive.zip', 'main.py', '.archive.zip.crc'])]
worker walk: ["[('./', ['archive.zip', '__spark_conf__', 'tmp'], ['pyspark.zip', '.default_container_executor.sh.crc', '.container_tokens.crc', 'default_container_executor.sh', 'launch_container.sh', '.launch_container.sh.crc', 'default_container_executor_session.sh', '.default_container_executor_session.sh.crc', 'py4j-0.10.9-src.zip', 'container_tokens']), ('./tmp', [], ['liblz4-java-5701923559211144129.so.lck', 'liblz4-java-5701923559211144129.so'])]"]
```

*The output for driver node*: The `archive.zip` is available but not extracted - **EXPECTED**

*The output for worker node*: `os.walk` is listing `archive.zip` as an extracted directory. The 3 directories available are  `['archive.zip', '__spark_conf__', 'tmp']`. But, to my surprise, only `./tmp` is further traveresed and that is it

I have checked using `os.listdir` that `archive.zip` actually is a directory and not a zip. It's structure is:

```
└── archive.zip
    └── archive
        ├── a1.py
        ├── a1.txt
        └── archive1
            ├── a1_in.py
            └── a1_in.txt
```

So, why is `os.walk` not walking down the `archive.zip` directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataproc does not unpack files passed as Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645635/dataproc-does-not-unpack-files-passed-as-archive)

Answer (score 0):

`archive.zip` is added as a symlink to worker nodes. Symlinks are not traversed by default.

If you change to `walk_worker = rdd.map(lambda x: str(list(os.walk('./', followlinks=True)))).distinct().collect()` you will get the output you are looking for:

```
worker walk: ["[('./', ['__spark_conf__', 'tmp', 'archive.zip'], ...
 ('./archive.zip', ['archive'], []), ('./archive.zip/archive', ['archive1'], ['a1.txt', 'a1.py']), ...."]
```