# Spark --archives file not found error, exception from executor

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am submitting a Spark job using Dataproc Serverless. My Spark code uses a few `.yaml` files as configuration and I pass them as `--archives` to the code.

Command to run the code:

```bash
gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark src/mapper.py \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID \
  --region=$REGION \
  --deps-bucket=$DEPS_BUCKET \
  --container-image=$CONTAINER_IMAGE \
  --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --subnet=$SUBNETWORK_URI \
  --py-files=dist/src.zip \
  --archives=dist/config.zip \
  -- --arg1="value1"
```

But I am getting an error with the below message:

```
An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tmp/spark/work/config/config.yaml'
```

Code used to access config:

```
with open("config/config.yaml", "r") as f:
    COUNTRY_CODES = yaml.load(f, yaml.SafeLoader)
```

How can I submit dependent files to Dataproc so that they will be available inside `/var/tmp/spark/work/` folder inside the executor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? You may need to use cluster mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645635/dataproc-does-not-unpack-files-passed-as-archive

Comment: How does your PySpark code look like for accessing the files?

Comment: You need to use `SparkFiles.get(filename)` to get the absolute path of the file at runtime https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkFiles.get.html

Comment: @Dagang Updated the question with the information.

Answer (score 1):

When you access files in the archive that are passed via `--archives` parameter to Spark job, you do not need to specify full path to these files, instead you need to use current working directory (`.`). In your specific case it probably will be `./config/config.yaml` (depends on folder structure inside your archive).

You can read more about Python package management in Spark docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

Comment: Does archives files get copied to executors and drivers as well?

Comment: Yes, it work the same on both driver and executors, but archives are not just copied, they are extracted to the current working directory of driver and executors.

Comment: Wanted to follow-up here, as I'm having a similar issue. I believe @IgorDvorzhak 's assertion that archies are extracted to the cwd of the driver is incorrect. In my experience, passed archives are only extracted in the workers - which is a huge problem for attempting to pass pyhton dependencies as a zip. You can test this yourself with a simle package and attempt to `import` something in the package. Dagang's linked comment shows the same issue, however I find that it has not been fixed for the Dataproc CLI.

Comment: @Paco I just tested this and it works as expected. May you share small repro that you use to test this functionality? Note that archive auto-extraction in the driver's working directory works only in Dataproc Serverless not on Dataproc Clusters. Also, for `import` to work, you need to configure Python accordingly: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html